# Create a SQL table with a varying number of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, say teacher and student. I want to build a third table called class.

The class table will have one column for the teacher of the class, but I want to see if their is an elegant way to represent the students. My first thought is to have say 30 columns.. student1, student2 and have quids for each of these that tie back to a row in the student table.

But I am asking to see if there is a more preferred solution. The above solution seems clunky.

Comment: Are you asking about how to store the students that are in each class, or how to select them such that you will see a column for each student in the class?  The structure of your tables does not necessarily have to correspond to how you would like your query results to look.

Comment: if you ever have a SQL table design where you have columns of the same name except an attached incrementing number (like your student1, student2...), you have a bad design! this is why they invented the phrase "just say no"

Comment: +1 for detecting the "database smell" of multiple columns when they should be rows.

Comment: @KM, yeah I knew it was bad was trying to think of a couple different ways to do it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was me I would have a 4th table called attendees or similar which links the students to the class as it's a many to many relationship. Which would contain the Class ID and the Student ID as a minimum..

Comment: +1 ... by all means yes ... I would do the same for teachers because is there only 1 and only 1 teacher for each class? e.g. ClassDetail(ClassID, PersonID, Role)

Comment: Selected this answer as it is the most straight forward. I need to look at the PIVOT solution but this solution works for now.

Comment: @Maestro1024 Take a look at my StudentClass table, it's exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

The class "table" is not a table but a result of running a stored procedure with pivoting of data.

And data structure is as follows:

```
Student: Id, ...
Teacher: Id, ...
StudentClass: StudentId, ClassId, ...
Class: Id, TeacherId, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has this thing called [sparse columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) However I would advice against it. Normalize your data and then [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)/crosstab the results when you want to display it side by side

Answer (score 2):

It's very clunky.

<strike>Have three tables:</strike>

1. Teacher
2. Student
3. TeacherStudent, which is a many-many table to join the two.

Do the pivot method expressed in the other answer. It makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes, but I think he's after the `PIVOT` keyword.